# Circulation of a vector field from point $A(1,1,1)$ to $B(2,2,2)$ in a straight conture

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Suppose I have $$\overrightarrow{F} = (yz + xy)\overrightarrow{i} + (xz+\frac{1}{2}x^2)\overrightarrow{j} + (xy + y^2z)\overrightarrow{k}$$

$A(1,1,1)$, $B(2,2,2)$

I need to calculate the circulation of the vector field in a straight conture from point A to point B. I know that

$$C = \int_{_{_{\large l}}} Pdx + Qdy + Rdz$$

However, how do I calculate the circulation here? I'm only given two points. The answer is $18$.

Comment: What's the main purpose of P Q and R? U made some mistakes or u have wrong idea about it... That should be $\hat i$ not $\vec i$. I think P is direction through x axis and Q and R is respectively y and z axes,isn’t it?

Comment: And, did u mean closed integral by circulation? Or is it something else?